# How to know the total how many views of knowledge article by each User?

Tags: apex, knowledge, articles

I want to know the one article how time viewed by particular one User (Total count of article view times for each User)? I need to create report for that data.

My Way Answer:

I gone through the Event file log is an object. In this object we have field called Event type=Knowledgeviewstate (Winer 18 update ). So i am thinking is we have a data in knowledgeviewstate but that was stored in file. I want store the data into one cutsom object and show report from that custom object?

[image]

In logfile I have data I want the data into csv file through apex and store in to my custom object?

I would like to each and every user and view count separately? One article each user how many times viewed and that user name also I want display?

How to concert data and store into Custom Object?

Comment: Hello every one any idea about this ??

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a custom visualforce page (or a community with lightning components) to display your articles, then you can include code in the controller for tge page or component to create a record for the custom object you mentioned. This is the approach I have taken, using a custom object where every view of an article saves the users name, department and other important fields as at the time of view into a record. You can then report on the custom object as needed. Its not ideal, but works.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Gopichand you can get achieved this by installing an app provided by salesforce "Knowledge Base dashboard & Reports" and currently I am using this app to get all reports regarding Articles.